# How to show hidden file to the right user - PHP

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url, filesystems

I want to be able to show a Image file to a user in HTML but not to other users and stop the wrong users to go to the URL of the image! So in other words allow access to a image URL to a specific user and stop the wrong users from going to the image URL!

Comment: How you can identify Wrong or Right Users? Use ACL in your application. read more about it from https://github.com/myclabs/ACL

Comment: use PHP  sessions and if condition within your HTML. https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: Is there a way to change htaccess with php?